# How to change the interval $n=m$ {book class}

Tags: margins, books

I want to change the page margins such that n = m (see the picture below).

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
    counter-format={No.}\,qu[],
  headings-format = \bfseries, 
  counter-within = section,
  headings=runin
}

\RenewQuSolPair{question}[name=Question]{solution}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
\chapter{TEST}

\newpage
\section{Daily TEST}
\begin{question}
    This is sample question 1. This is sample question 1. This is sample question 1. This is sample question 1. This is sample question 1. This is sample question 1. 
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    This is sample solution 1. 
\end{solution}
\vfill

\vfill
\begin{question}
    This is sample question 2.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    This is sample solution 2. 
\end{solution}
\vfill

\newpage
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using the twoside option to book?

Comment: There is no reason!!!

Comment: @Hugh - `twoside` is the default for the `book` document class; simply not mentioning it won't help achieve the OP's objective. It's necessary to specify `oneside` explicitly, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the document class option `twoside`. Instead, use the option `oneside`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
```

Answer (score 2):

See package `geometry`. For example

```
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 3cm, right = 2cm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin = 3cm, rmargin = 2cm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin = {3cm,2cm}]{geometry}
```

etc. For other possibilities see package documentation.